# Can the address of a variable with automatic storage duration be taken in its definition?

Tags: c, language-lawyer, c11

Is it allowed to take the address of an object on the right hand-side of its definition, as happens in `foo()` below:

```
typedef struct { char x[100]; } chars;

chars make(void *p) {
  printf("p = %p\n", p);
  chars c;
  return c;
}

void foo(void) {
  chars b = make(&b);
}
```

If it is allowed, is there any restriction on its use, e.g., is printing it OK, can I compare it to another pointer, etc?

In practice it seems to compile on the compilers I tested, with the expected behavior most of the time (but [not always](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50664325/149138)), but that's far from a guarantee.

Comment: Did you read the C11 standard [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)? The answer is there (and your question has the wrong terminology)

Comment: I didn't. I welcome help with my terminology! One of the difficulties is that it's hard to ask about the terminology sometimes without already knowing the correct terminology. So let the code speak for itself here in case something is unclear about the question: I'm interesting if the `&b` is legal in the `chars b = make(&b)` line.

Comment: So read that C11 standard document first.

Comment: I think I'll get my answer here long before I make my way though 701 pages of dense standardese :).

Comment: AFAIK this is perfectly fine, but I'd have to read a few hundred pages of standardese to figure out why.

Comment: Heh. To be fair, if someone gives me a hint on where to look, I'm not averse to parsing the standard, but I wouldn't know where to start in this case.

Comment: It will take several parts threaded together, both the [6.7 Declarations](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7) and [6.5.3.2 Address and indirection operators](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.3.2), and the answer will probably be the declaration (and definition) creates an `lvalue` to which the *unary* `&` operator may be applied. (there may be further sections that come into play on function parameter sequencing, but nothing sticks out)

Comment: The address passed into the function has not yet been constructed, so a complex object, would not work within the call.

Comment: @mksteve Fortunately this is C and there are no constructors.

Comment: Let’s try and be sensible here; else are we to close all C questions as duplicates to the standard?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> **6.2.1 Scopes of identifiers**
>
> 7. Structure, union, and enumeration tags have scope that begins just after the appearance of
>      the tag in a type specifier that declares the tag.  Each enumeration constant has scope that
>      begins  just  after  the  appearance  of  its  defining  enumerator  in  an  enumerator  list. **Any
>      other identifier has scope that begins just after the completion of its declarator.**

In

```
chars b = make(&b);
//    ^^
```

the declarator is `b`, so it is in scope in its own initializer.

> **6.2.4 Storage durations of objects**
>
> 6. For  such  an [automatic] object  that  does  not  have  a  variable  length  array  type,  its  lifetime  extends
>      from entry into the block with which it is associated until execution of that block ends in
>      any way.

So in

```
{ // X
  chars b = make(&b);
}
```

the lifetime of `b` starts at `X`, so by the time the initializer executes, it is both alive and in scope.

As far as I can tell, this is effectively identical to

```
{
  chars b;
  b = make(&b);
}
```

There's no reason you couldn't use `&b` there.

Comment: Thanks. I was asking due to [this unexpected behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50664325/149138) and I wasn't sure if taking the address in the definition was not allowed and so triggering it.

Answer (score 8):

To answer the question in the title, with your code sample in mind, yes it may. The C standard says as much in [**§6.2.4**](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.4):

> The lifetime of an object is the portion of program execution during
>   which storage is guaranteed to be reserved for it. An object exists,
>   has a constant address, and retains its last-stored value throughout
>   its lifetime.
>
> For such an object that does not have a variable length array type,
>   its lifetime extends from entry into the block with which it is
>   associated until execution of that block ends in any way.

So yes, you may take the address of a variable from the point of declaration, because the object has the address at this point and it's in scope. A condensed example of this is the following:

```
void *p = &p;
```

It serves very little purpose, but is perfectly valid.

As for your second question, what can you do with it. I can mostly say I wouldn't use that address to access the object until initialization is complete, because the order of evaluation for expressions in initializers is left unsepcified ([**§6.7.9**](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.9p23)). You can easily find your foot shot off.

One place where this does come through, is when defining all sorts of tabular data structures that need to be self referential. For instance:

```
typedef struct tab_row {
  // Useful data
  struct tab_row *p_next;
} row;

row table[3] = {
  [1] = { /*Data 1*/, &table[0] },
  [2] = { /*Data 2*/, &table[1] },
  [0] = { /*Data 0*/, &table[2] },
};
```

Comment: Is it safe to compare for this pointer for equality to another?

Comment: @BeeOnRope Depends on which operator you use. `==` or `!=` is fine. `<` and friends require operands that point into the same array.

Answer (score 0):

The question has already been answered, but for reference, it doesn't make much sense. This is how you would write the code:

```
typedef struct { char x[100]; } chars;

chars make (void) {
  chars c;
  /* init c */
  return c;
}

void foo(void) {
  chars b = make();
}
```

Or perhaps preferably in case of an ADT or similar, return a pointer to a `malloc`:ed object. Passing structs by value is usually not a good idea.