# Can two different objects with automatic storage duration compare equal under address comparison?

Tags: c, x86, clang

In particular, is it allowed for the addresses of two automatic variables in different functions to compare equal as follows:

**sink.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void sink(void *l, void *r) {
    puts(l == r ? "equal" : "not equal");
    exit(0);
}
```

**main.c**

```
typedef struct { char x[32]; } Foo;

void sink(void *l, void *r);

Foo make(void *p) {
    Foo f2;
    sink(&f2, p);
    return f2;
}

int main() {
    Foo f1 = make(&f1);
}
```

I would expect this to print `not equal` as `f1` and `f2` are distinct objects. With gcc I get `not equal`, but with my local version of clang 3.8<sup>1</sup>, it prints `equal`, when compiled as `clang -O1 sink.c main.c`<sup>2</sup>.

Disassembling `make` and `main` ...

```
0000000000400570 <make>:
  400570:   53                      push   rbx
  400571:   48 89 fb                mov    rbx,rdi
  400574:   e8 d7 ff ff ff          call   400550 <sink>
  400579:   48 89 d8                mov    rax,rbx
  40057c:   5b                      pop    rbx
  40057d:   c3                      ret    
  40057e:   66 90                   xchg   ax,ax

0000000000400580 <main>:
  400580:   48 83 ec 28             sub    rsp,0x28
  400584:   48 8d 7c 24 08          lea    rdi,[rsp+0x8]
  400589:   48 89 fe                mov    rsi,rdi
  40058c:   e8 df ff ff ff          call   400570 <make>
  400591:   31 c0                   xor    eax,eax
  400593:   48 83 c4 28             add    rsp,0x28
  400597:   c3                      ret
```

... we see that `make` never seems to create the `Foo f2` object at all, it just calls `sink` with the existing `rdi` and `rsi` (the `l` and `r` parameters, respectively). These are passed by `main` and are the same: the first, `rdi`, is the hidden pointer to the location to put the return value, and the second is `&f1`, so we expect these to be the same.

---

<sup>1</sup> I checked versions up to 7.0 and the behavior is roughly the same.

<sup>2</sup> It happens for `-O1`, `-O2` and `-O3`, but not `-O0` which prints `not equal` instead.

Comment: Are you telling me the compiler doesn’t warn about the call to make?

Comment: @Fred - Correct. Is there a problem with it?

Comment: Just seems like a very strange way to pass a local variable, it’s not clear if it’s been created or not at the time of the call.

Comment: @r3musn0x on the [c] tag questions are about Standard C unless otherwise specified

Comment: I'm asking whether this is allowed by the language, like most "Can X happen" questions. It's not clear that the pointers are comparing equal in my case: perhaps there is some UB lurking in my program that lets the compiler do whatever it wants. I suppose I could have left the clang behavior out entirely, but compiler behavior usually serves as a good positive test for what the standard allows. @r3

Comment: I am curious to know what happens if `Foo f1 = make(&f1);` is rewrote as `Foo f1; f1 = make(&f1);`

Comment: @Fredrik - yeah it's weird, but the consensus seems to be that it is allowed. It isn't clear to me that it is strictly necessary to get the "equals" result, but breaking that into two statements does change the behavior to "not equal" with the current example.

Comment: @Tanguy - it prints "not equal".

Comment: Compiler bug. Overzealous optimizer. The result **must be** "not equals".

Comment: [Report it as a Clang/LLVM miscompilation](https://llvm.org/docs/HowToSubmitABug.html#miscompilations)

Comment: the same with gcc

Comment: but the problem in bad construction `Foo f1 = make(&f1);` if replace it to `Foo f1 ; make(&f1);` error disappear. interesting that also error only in case array size > 16. if set `x[16]` or less - also correct code. really impossible return "big" object by value. all compilers in case this code pass hidden additional parameter to function which must return object. something like `make(&f1, &f1);` will be real signature

Comment: @RbMm on what versionn of GCC did you observe the "equal" behavior?

Comment: @BeeOnRope - on all versions of *gcc*. also on zapcc, ellcc - https://godbolt.org/g/CmiFqM but main detail - use function which return object. try reproduce this without object return ?

Comment: @RbMm - that's C++, but this question is about C. In the C++ the rules are different, in particular RVO. Use the drop-down in godbolt to select C.

Comment: with *c* i really view this only with *clang*, but i about another - construction, when function return object, which not fit to generic register size - not good. i never use this for example. can you found bug like this, without using return object by value

Comment: No idea if the same thing happens without return-by-value, and that's not the point. Returning objects by value is a common idiom in C, as is passing pointers to arguments.  They should both work correctly, and I shouldn't need to care about how the ABIs returns values in register, except perhaps for the tightest inner loops.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The C11 standard part 6.5.9/6 says:

> Two pointers compare equal if and only if both are null pointers, both are pointers to the same object (including a pointer to an object and a subobject at its beginning) or function, both are pointers to one past the last element of the same array object, or one is a pointer to one past the end of one array object and the other is a pointer to the start of a different array object that happens to immediately follow the first array object in the address space.

In this code none of the listed conditions hold; `&f1` and `&f2` are pointers to different objects, and one is not a subobject of the other.

So the pointers must not compare equal. The compiler reporting `equal` is non-conforming.

---

*Note:* If anyone has doubts about the legality of `Foo f1 = make(&f1);`, [see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50663893/).  It is fine and the automatic object's lifetime begins at the preceding `{`.

Comment: You should add the first sentence from [6.2.4p6](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.4p6)

Comment: Ah, so you could link that one here too, for a casual reader. I hadn't read that other one yet.

Comment: may be this and compiler (*gcc,clang,zapcc*) bug, but construction, when function return object (not fit general register size) is bad by design (by my opinion). technically direct do this impossible. when some function (`T fn()`) return object - compiler need pass additional hidden parameter to this function - pointer to object - `T t = fn();` will be implemented as `T t; fn(&t)` really always. and if we write construction `T fn(T*)` and `T t = fn(&t)` - not very surprised that some compiler implement this as `T t; fn(&t, &t)`

Comment: @RbMm we're not surprised either, but it is still wrong.

Comment: @RbMm - as mentioned in the comment thread on the question, those other compilers do this in _C++_, not C. In C++ this optimization is probably valid due to RVO and/or NRVO which explicitly allows objects to be elided in this case.

Comment: @BeeOnRope: The optimization for `make` can't possibly be right in C++ unless the compiler knows what `sink` is going to do with the pointers it receives.  Whether or not the compiler would know of anything that would ever cares about the contents of `f2`, `sink` is allowed to make use of 32 bytes of storage at `*l` without disrupting anything else.  If some other compilation unit held `void sink(void *l, void *r) { *(char*)r = 1; *(char*)l = 2; }`, the generated code for `make` would result in `*p` being correctly written with 1 and then erroneously written with 2.

Comment: @supercat C++ has other provisions limiting what is defined for objects under construction;  in C++ the lifetime of `f1` doesn't begin until after the function has returned whereas in C the lifetime of `f1` begins on entry to the block

Comment: @M.M: The code generated for `main` might legitimately act upon that assumption, but the "stand-alone" code generated for `make` receives a pointer and then passes that pointer, along with the address if its own object `f2`, to `sink`; the lifetime of `f2` clearly *does* begin before the call to `sink`.

Comment: @supercat - I'm not following you regarding the generated assembly for `make`: it doesn't pass the same pointer for `l` and `r`, it passes a different pointer for each: `&f2` for `l` (in `rdi`) and `p` for `r` (in `rsi`). (Of course, the caller might arrange for them to be the same). In your example, as long as the caller of `make` passed something other than the address of the return value of `make`, the storage locations will be separate. I think the code is only questionable in concert with the `main()` function.

Comment: @M.M: The lifetime of `f1` doesn't begin until its constructor completes, but it already has storage and a pointer to an object whose initialization is not yet complete is allowed to be used in limited ways.

Comment: In C++, the optimization is valid due to NRVO: "When certain criteria are met, an implementation is allowed to omit the copy/move construction of a class object, even if the constructor selected for the copy/move operation and/or the destructor for the object have side eﬀects. **In such cases, the implementation treats the source and target of the omitted copy/move operation as simply two diﬀerent ways of referring to the same object.**"

Comment: @BeeOnRope: My bad.  I mistook RBX as an argument.  Every once in a while I need a clue-by-four, so bonk away. `>:*3`

Comment: @BenVoigt: I wonder if that was intended to apply even in cases where an object's address is taken.  IMHO, production of a pointer to an object of a particular type should be regarded as a sequenced action, and such recognition could allow many other rules to be simplified while making the language more powerful, but for whatever reason compilers tend to treat it as a non-action.

Comment: @supercat: I'm pretty sure that phrasing was chosen to answer that exact question.

Comment: @BenVoigt: I meant cases where the address is taken using the `&` operator in the context of its definition.

Comment: @supercat: Or any other way of detecting aliasing.  But it's not clear to me what aliasing apart from this case that rule would allow -- to me, it surely is intended to apply to this case.

Comment: @BenVoigt: If an assignment is performed upon an object which has previously had member functions run, such functions might store `this` into an object with static or heap duration.  I think the rule was intended to exempt compilers from having ensure that the address of the temporary object under construction not match any potential copy of the destination object's address *when there is no particular evidence to suggest that such a copy exists*.  That is a very different situation from one where `&` is used on the object in the same context as the initialization or assignment.

Comment: @BenVoigt: The authors of C89 regarded compilers' ability to recognize potential aliasing as a Quality-of-Implementation issue rather than a conformance one, and thus made no effort to specify all the situations a quality compiler should recognize.  Subsequent issues of the C Standard have continued treating the matter as a QoI issue, and while I've not read most of the C++ Standards I suspect--given their derivation from C Standards, they probably do so as well.

Comment: @supercat: In this case, the "higher quality" is better optimization.  The rule is written to allow the optimization even in the face of code that behaves differently when the copy is elided.

Comment: @BenVoigt: At least in C, the stated purpose of such rules (given in the Rationale) is to allow optimizations in situations where there was no *particular* evidence that they would affect program behavior.  Do constructs like `Foo f1=make(&f1);` occur often enough that blocking optimizations in such cases would meaningfully degrade performance?

Comment: @supercat: Do they occur often enough to be worth making the language rules more complicated, the compiler more complicated, and if the wording doesn't catch 100% of cases, is the inconsistent behavior better than unexpected-but-consistent behavior?

Comment: @supercat: For example, here is another variation on the exact same thing: `Foo f1{make(&f1)};`  A simple change from copy-initialization to direct-initialization using a copy constructor.  But that leads to `Foo * pf = new (p) Foo{make(p)};`.  Same case, but `p` didn't come from application of address-of.  And might have been passed via a global, as you previously commented.

Comment: @BenVoigt: I don't understand the latter example; did you mean `Foo *p`? And if so, would the value of `p` be usable before the constructor finished? As for making things more complicated, the general principle is simple: when `&` is applied to an object, operations on the resulting pointer are sequenced after any preceding operations involving that object, and before the next time the object is used in a way not involving that pointer or execution enters a function or loop wherein that occurs. A premise of copy-value elision is that nothing would care about when the new object is created.

Comment: If nothing would care, there would be no elision rule, because "as-if" would cover it all.  Elision specifically allows (and in C++17, can require) optimizations that can be detected.  An important thing to note is that the optimization still doesn't break useful code.  It puts an object at the pointer before one was expected to exist there -- if there wasn't one existing there, you couldn't use the pointer, just store it for use after construction completes.